# tags from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, tags

From what I understand relational databases are ill-equipped to handle polymorphic relationships, but is there any easy way of integrating multiple tables into one tags table. Basically what I want to achieve is to have one tags table, but have the tag names derived from 1 of 3 table (games, platforms or companies). See the below design as a mock-up:

[image]

Am I looking at this from the wrong way or am I on the right track? Is there a different approach someone would suggest?

Comment: use inheritance from a generic tag table down to specialized tables (single table with classifier column or multi table)

Comment: How about having a `name` and `tag_type_id` fields in the `tags` table? `tag_type_id` is the id of a row from another table `tag_types(id, name)` (this table should have rows like (1, 'games'), (2, 'platforms'), (3, 'companies') etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case sounds like a mismatch between relational modeling and object modeling.  If you are interested in designing relational tables that provide the closest thing to inheritance (not polymorphism) then look up the questions, answers, and info under these tags:
[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)

If you're interested in more detail, look up Martin Fowler's handling of the same techniques.

If your interest is in diagramming the IS-A relationship between games, platforms, or companies and some unnamed superclass that I'll call "Tag Providers" , then look up "EER generalization/specialization".  (EER stands for Enhanced Entity Relationship).  This shows how to diagram the relationship, without providing any details about how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct as there is Many to many relationship between article,video & tags.

See,
One  article => with => Many tags 
One tag => belongs to => Many articles .

So to preserve mapping 3rd,4th mapping table is necessary .

3rd Table will  have relationship between Article+Tags

4th Table will  have relationship between Video+Tags

**Update =>**

For other tables to relate with Tags table , Make 3 more tables :

5th Table will have relationship between Company+Tags  => `companies_tags`

6th Table will have relationship between Game+Tags   => `games_tags`

7th Table will have relationship between Platform+Tags => `platforms_tags`

Comment: Im not sure exactly what uyou mean. I already know how to hook up the tags table to the articles and videos tables, but how do I connect the games, platforms and companies table to the tags table?

Comment: @NicholasLaw then you shuold explicitely state in Your Question that u want to connect Tags table to Company table , platform table